# SimpleDateFormat is giving wrong day

Tags: android, android-studio, simpledateformat

```
public void setDate(View view){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

       new DatePickerDialog(CreateEventActivity.this,listener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar setTime=Calendar.getInstance();
            setTime.set(year,monthOfYear+1,dayOfMonth);
            eventDate=setTime.getTime();

            SimpleDateFormat dayFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            eventDayOfWeek=dayFormat.format(eventDate);

            Context appContext=getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(appContext,(appContext.getString(R.string.The_chosen_date_is))+": "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year+","+eventDayOfWeek,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dateTxt.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
            dayTxt.setText(eventDayOfWeek);


        }
    };
```

I'm trying to show the user the date that he chose(by date picker). The date in numbers is fine, but the day in string is wrong, 2 days forward.For example: instead of Saturday it writes Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong month. [`OnDateSetListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.html) months are zero-based like [`Calendar`'s](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) and you don't need to `+1` adjust them here:

> ```
> setTime.set(year,monthOfYear+1,dayOfMonth);
> ```